# ArcGIS Collector Sync Replica Internal Error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-collector

I have downloaded maps on arc collector for offline use but whenever I try to sync, it gives me the message "Unable to synchronize replica. Sync Replica Internal Error". To note, many users have been using the same map from different devices.

To experiment, I created a new map with the same feature layer as the map mentioned above, downloaded it to a device, created a point, and had no issues with syncing.

Long story short, I am assuming that my issue is that I have several users adding data to the same map. Everyone downloaded the map to their device since we are using this for emergency response after a hurricane and were not sure if we would have cell service after the storm. Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

If necessary, I can transcribe the data from each device individually, but that is not ideal.

Comment: Collector designed for multiple users. Simply try again few hours later. Agol health dashboard does not tell full story sometimes.

Comment: Did you change the schema? That would explain the error. Not sure if this is appropriate, but you may want to try AmigoCollect instead and I would personally assign somebody to help you through the same use case. You can then use the ArcGIS Sync tool to sync back to your GDB - it supports multiple user edits *and* schema editing (which Collector does not). http://www.amigocloud.com